# EDIT: How would I go about inlining these span and imgs in CSS?

Tags: css, image, inline, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
        <div id="page" class="cf">
            <a href="#" id="latest">
                <img src="images/fzero.png"/>
                <span> VGC - F-ZERO (SNES) game review</span>
            </a>
        <div class="feature-bar cf">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="videos" href="">
                            <img src="images/mario.png" />
                            <span>VGC - Super Mario 64 game review</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="videos" href="">
                            <img src="images/sf2t.png" />
                            <span>VGC - Street Fighter 2 Turbo (SNES) game review</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="videos" href="">
                            <img src="images/tekken2.png"/>
                            <span>VGC - TEKKEN 2 (PlayStation) game review</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="videos" href="">
                            <img src="images/Nintendo64.png"/>
                            <span>VGC - Nintendo 64 console review</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="videos" href="">
                            <img src="images/Nintendo64.png"/>
                            <span>VGC - Nintendo 64 console review</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
        </div>
```

I'm sorry that I didn't explain it well. But with the spans I wanted them to be under the img but centered in middle. I've made the divs into an unordered list, or should I leave them as divs?

This is my CSS, for it (I'm a beginner and started a fresh project.)

```
/* F-ZERO */
a#latest img, a#latest span {margin: 30px 0 0 50px;}
a#latest img {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 display:block;
 max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 100%;
}
/* FEATURE BAR*/
a#latest span {text-align: center;}

a.videos img {
 max-width: 150px;
}
a.videos span {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: put your existing css here.

Answer (score 0):

`img` and `span` are already inline elements, you need to change the display of div to inline

```
.feature-bar div {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code, I think you want something like this.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raoei)